# Java GUI library toString() as a display method

Tags: java

Why do Java GUI classes use `toString()` to display stuff to the end-user instead of a `getDisplay()` type method provided from an interface?

For example:

JavaFX:

- `ListView`
- `TreeView`

It would make more sense to have this interface:

```
public interface Displayable{
    public StringProperty displayProperty();
    public String getDisplay();
}
```

For one, `toString()` only returns a static response and to get an update, it would require recalling it. If a `Property` was used, only calling it once would be required. I always thought that `toString()` was just used for debugging purposes for telling the object type or if it is null quickly.

I guess if you have `ListView<String>`, calling `toString()` would return the `String`, I guess that would be one drawback of the `Displayable` interface.

Comment: I am asking if there is reason for using `toString()` instead of another method. Why has such time gone by and this hasn't changed?

Comment: It seems like such a stupid decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two main reasons:

### Consistency:

Every object propagates from the `Object` class, and it has the default method `toString()` to format itself for output. This has become the standard for all its children, as they all inherit it.

### Non-GUI Classes:

A static display is useful for most objects, as they are not GUI based. They occur in a program that is executed and then exits, so their value is static when you are viewing it. Additionally, it is useful to be able to see how the values of a variable are different in different places in a program. If the output was updated with the variable, this chronological view of change would be lost. Furthermore, `toString()` is mostly for outputting objects to a file/command line, which are inherently static and cannot be overwritten by a dynamic method without deletion.

Comment: I understand if the object is static, but it should be assumed that the object is non-static. I have had lots of cases in a bean where the output is formatted and changing the bean should update the string representation. This would require tedious listeners and many calls to `toString()` whereas a simple property would be much simpler.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, but you have to understand that most objects **output to a static location**. Thus assuming the opposite would be *incorrect* for **most objects**.